# How is "__builtin_va_list" implemented?

Tags: c, gcc, clang

I want to delve into the implementation of function "printf" in C on macOS. "printf" uses the `<stdarg.h>` header file. I open the `<stdarg.h>` file and find that `va_list` is just a macro.

So, I am really curious about how the `__builtin_va_list` is implemented? I know it is compiler-specific. Where can I find the definition of the `__builtin_va_list`? Should I download the source code of clang compiler?

Comment: "Built-in" means that it is, indeed, implemented inside the compiler, using information that wouldn't be available to a normal function or macro.

Comment: Those are just implementation details, the gist is it parses the format for tokens the. Pops the correct number of bytes off of the stack for each of those tokens... google variadic functions in C

Comment: Curious: on my Mac, I find `#ifndef _VA_LIST` — 
`typedef __builtin_va_list va_list;` — 
`#define _VA_LIST`  (in file `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/9.1.0/include/stdarg.h`) so `va_list` is a typedef, not a macro.  However, that's a mere wording issue.  AFAIK, you'd have to poke around the source of `clang` to find out how it is handled because it is a built-in type.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler... va_list has to be a type you pass it to va_list, `va_arg`, `va_end`... `__VA_ARGS__` is the macro that gets expanded in macro expansion.

Comment: @GradyPlayer: I'm not sure what relevance `__VA_ARGS__` has to this discussion.  I don't mention it.  It is a preprocessor feature and `va_list` is not primarily a preprocessor feature.  I assume that the OP was claiming that there was `#define va_list __builtin_va_list` ("find that `va_list` is just a macro") whereas I find that it is a typedef.  However, that is mostly a wording issue for the purposes of the question.

Comment: you are right, of course... I think I was confused mostly by: `"However, that's a mere wording issue"`

Answer (score 8):

> So, I am really curious about how the __builtin_va_list is implemented?

`__builtin_va_list` is implemented *inside* the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler (or the [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/) one). So you should study the GCC compiler source code to understand details.

Look into [gcc/builtins.def](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/gcc/builtins.def?view=markup) & [gcc/builtins.c](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/gcc/builtins.c?view=markup) for more.

I am less familiar with [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/), which implements the same builtin.

But both GCC & Clang are open source or free software. They are complex beasts (several millions lines of code each), so you could need years of work to understand them.

Be aware that the [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) of your compiler matters. Look for example into [X86 psABI](https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/X86-psABI) for more details.

BTW, [Grady Player](https://stackoverflow.com/users/593382/grady-player) commented:

> <sup>Pops the correct number of bytes off of the stack for each of those tokens...</sup>

Unfortunately, today it is much more complex than that. On current processors and ABIs the [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) do use [processor registers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_register) to pass some arguments (and the evil is in the details).

> Should I download the source code of clang compiler?

Yes, and you also need to allocate several years of work to understand the details.

A few years ago, I did write some tutorial slides and links to external documentation regarding GCC implementation, see my [GCC MELT documentation](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/gcc-melt/docum.html) page (a bit rotten).

Comment: the x86-64 abi does use registers but not for variadic functions.

Comment: Perhaps the carry bit might be used for them. I forgot details

Comment: @GradyPlayer As far as I can tell, variadic functions are called with arguments in registers just like other functions; additionally, %al must be set to the number of vector registers used for float arguments. https://c9x.me/compile/doc/abi.html

Answer (score 2):

In Clang 9, this is implemented in

```
clang\lib\AST\ASTContext.cpp
```

call graph:

```
getVaListTagDecl
=>getBuiltinVaListDecl
=>CreateVaListDecl
=>Create***BuiltinVaListDecl
for example:
=>CreateCharPtrBuiltinVaListDecl
=>CreateCharPtrNamedVaListDecl
=>buildImplicitTypedef
```

When there is __builtin_va_list in the preprocessed source, the compiler calls getVaListTagDecl to build a TypedefDecl AST node and insert it into the AST, the typedef doesn't exist in any source code, it is generated dynamically during build, as if there is such in the source:

```
typedef *** __builtin_va_list;
//for example
typedef char* __builtin_va_list;
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer, for clang, just show how I find implementation of a builtin function.

I'm interested in implementation of `std::atomic<T>`. If `T` is not a trivial type, clang use a lock to guard its atomicity. Look [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50298358/where-is-the-lock-for-a-stdatomic/50298847#50298847) first, I find a builtin function named `__c11_atomic_store`. The question is, how this builtin function implemented in clang?

Searching `Builtin` in clang codebase, find in `clang/Basic/Builtins.def`:

```
// Some of our atomics builtins are handled by AtomicExpr rather than
// as normal builtin CallExprs. This macro is used for such builtins.
#ifndef ATOMIC_BUILTIN
#define ATOMIC_BUILTIN(ID, TYPE, ATTRS) BUILTIN(ID, TYPE, ATTRS)
#endif

// C11 _Atomic operations for <stdatomic.h>.
ATOMIC_BUILTIN(__c11_atomic_init, "v.", "t")
ATOMIC_BUILTIN(__c11_atomic_load, "v.", "t")
ATOMIC_BUILTIN(__c11_atomic_store, "v.", "t")
ATOMIC_BUILTIN(__c11_atomic_exchange, "v.", "t")
...
```

The keyword are `AtomicExpr` and `CallExpr`. Then I check every caller of `AtomicExpr`'s constructor, but doesn't find any useful information. So I guess, maybe in parse phase, if parser match an builtin function calling, it will construct an `CallExpr` to AST with builtin flag. In code generate phase, it will emit the implementation.

Check `CodeGen`, I find the answer in `lib/CodeGen/CGBuiltin.cpp` and `CodeGen/CGAtomic.cpp`.

You can check `CodeGenFunction::EmitVAArg`, I holp that would be useful for you.

Comment: I post here because of length limitation of comment.