# va_list passed to a function using va_arg is not working

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

I've this code that plays with variadic functions:

```
#include <cstdarg>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void bar(va_list vl) {
    std::cout << va_arg(vl, T) << std::endl;
}

void foo(int n, ...) {
    va_list vl;
    va_start(vl, n);
    while (n--) {
        bar<int>(vl);
    }
    va_end(vl);
}

int main() {
    foo(3, 1, 2, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, the output of this code is platform dependent. In GCC 7 I get:

```
1
2
3
```

while in MSVC 2015 is

```
1
1
1
```

I'm tring to write code to get the GCC output, but I suppose I'm doing something wrong and I've no idea where. Which is the correct output, if any?

Both compilers are set at maximum warning level, but they are not printing any warning.
In MSVC, being `va_list` an alias to `char*`, the output makes sense. In GCC it is a [builtin type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49733154/how-is-builtin-va-list-implemented) and I've no idea what happens there.

**Edit:**

If I change the definition of `bar` to `void bar(va_list& vl)` then the outputs are the same. Is it legal to pass a `va_list` by reference?

Comment: [Pro Tip] Don't use old c-style variadic functions.  Prefer C++'s variadic templates instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your program invokes undefined behavior.

The [semantics of C standard library in C++](http://eel.is/c++draft/library.c) is the same as in C and the content of [cstdarg](http://eel.is/c++draft/cstdarg.syn#1) should be the same as `stdarg.h` in C. C++ standard is big, so I'll use C standard here, which is easier for me to read. From [C99 7.15.3](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#7.15p3), annotation mine:

> .... The object ap [of type va_list, my annotation]  may be passed as an argument to another function; if that function invokes the va_arg macro with parameter ap, the value of ap in the calling function is indeterminate and shall be passed to the va_end macro prior to any further reference to ap.

If you pass `va_list` object to another function and in that function you call `va_arg`, you have to call `va_end` in the same function.

According to the [footnote 221 from C99](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#note221) you can pass a pointer to `va_list`.

Comment: Is it legal to pass `va_list` by reference? It seems to work, too.

Comment: This is a good question. If it's legal, I don't know. Sure, the semantics of using reference vs, like, dereferenced pointer should be the same, so it should work. Note that the parameter left of `...` can't be a reference, from [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/cstdarg.syn#1).

Comment: @GiovanniCerretani You could use a pointer instead of reference. That's allowed as per C standard.

Answer (score 0):

You should use modern C++11 approach. Using old fashion C variadic function is to dangerous.

You could use C++ template parameter pack, but in your case simple [std::initializer_list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) just do the job and it is quite handy:

```cpp
void foo(std::initializer_list<int> items) {
    for (auto item : items) {
        std::cout << item  << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    foo({1, 2, 3});

    return 0;
}
```

[demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/2j09qpU0qud9yq04)