# Is it legal to pass va_list as a reference to a function in C++?

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, variadic-functions

Upon code review/clang-tidy runs, I came across a function with a signature like this:

```cpp
void appendFoo(const char * fmt, va_list& rVaList);
```

I have never seen this before.
Afaik, you can pass `va_list` by value (and maybe by pointer?).

This brings me to my first question: **Is passing `va_list` by reference legal and does it work as expected?**

Anyway, `appendFoo()` calls `vsprintf()` in its definition and clang-tidy gave the following warning: `Function 'vsprintf' is called with an uninitialized va_list argument [clang-analyzer-valist.Uninitialized]`. The definition of `appendFoo()` look basically like this:

```cpp
void appendFoo(const char * fmt, va_list& rVaList) {
  // retracted: allocate buffer

  vsprintf(buffer, fmt, rVaList);

  // errorhandling
  // de-allocate buffer
}
```

(Yes, the return value of `vsprintf` is ignored and errors are "handled" another way. I'm fixing it ...)

In particular, no `va_copy`, `va_start`, etc. are called.

Removing the reference and passing `va_list` by value, i.e. changing the signature to `void appendFoo(const char * fmt, va_list rVaList);`, eliminates the clang-tidy warning.

This brings me to my second question: **Is the warning produced by clang-tidy if `va_list` is passed by reference a false-positive or is there is actually a problem in passing `va_list` as reference?**

---

PS: This question is *not* a duplicate of [varargs(va_list va_start) doesn't work with pass-by-reference parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184401/varargsva-list-va-start-doesnt-work-with-pass-by-reference-parameter). The OP of that question passes an argument by reference to a function taking a va_list. I'm asking about va_list itself being passed as a reference. Oh, well.

Comment: In my opinion va_list should not be used in C++ at all (it is a "C" relic that is not typesafe, prone to errors/safety issues etc.). You should use templates with parameter packs : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack, and forget all about va_list

Comment: I think this is illegal. Because `va_list` definition is *unspecified* : https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic/va_list I guess an implementation is free to use something incompatible with references (although I cannot find an example).

Comment: Unlike @PepijnKramer, I don't think we should avoid `va_list` at C++. But use them very carefully. On our C++ code base, string formatting functions are variadic template functions building up a type string, that is passed by to a private variadic C function. Inspired from here (but heavily enhanced afterwards): https://gist.github.com/deplinenoise/6297411

Comment: Nice question! Also take a look at the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: @prapin are there types that are incompatible with references?

Comment: That seems like either a false positive (since passing a pointer is valid, I would expect the same from a reference) or a problem with how you're calling `appendFoo`.

Comment: @GiovanniCerretani: if `va_list` is implemented as a macro, chances are that using it with a reference could lead to unexpected results...

Comment: `va_list` cannot be implemented as a macro, it must be a complete object type. Anyway, I asked a similar question, you may find some details in the comments of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60041534/3287591 In short: since it is unclear if it is legal to use references to `va_list`, use pointers to `va_list` that are allowed as per C standard.

Comment: The question is not a duplicate. It is about passing `va_list` itself as reference, the other question talks about the second argument passed to `va_start`.

Comment: @GiovanniCerretani I have re-opened it

Comment: There is no gain in passing va_list by reference. It's just a pointer.

Comment: I see no reason to believe that it wouldn't work. As was mentioned above, `va_list` must be a complete object type, so references to it can't behave strangely. It can't be something like `void` (where forming a reference would be ill-formed).

Comment: "In particular, no va_copy, va_start, etc. are called" - Not calling `va_start` and `va_end` is certainly a bug - it's [UB](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) to not do so.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is allowed. Firstly, [[cstdarg.syn]](https://eel.is/c++draft/cstdarg.syn) states:

> The contents of the header  are the same as the C standard library header <stdarg.h>, with the following changes:
>
> - [...]

None of the restrictions here disallow forming a reference to a `std::va_list`.

#### Relevant wording in the C standard

The answer lies in the [C17 standard, 7.16 Variable arguments <stdarg.h>, p3](https://cigix.me/c17#7.16.p3):

> The type declared is
>
> ```c
> va_list
> ```
>
> which is a complete object type suitable for holding information needed by the
> macros `va_start`, `va_arg`, `va_end`, and `va_copy`. If access to the varying arguments is desired, the called function
> shall declare an object (generally referred to as `ap` in this subclause) having type `va_list`.
> The object `ap` may be passed as an argument to another function; if that function invokes the `va_arg` macro
> with parameter `ap`, the value of `ap` in the calling function is indeterminate and shall be passed to the
> `va_end` macro prior to any further reference to `ap`.<sup>257)</sup>
>
> <sup>257)</sup> It is permitted to create a pointer to a `va_list` and pass that pointer to another function, in which case the original function may make further use of the original list after the other function returns.

Essentially, passing a `std::va_list` by pointer allows the callee to use the `std::va_list` as if we had used it in our own function.
Since `std::va_list` is a complete object type, binding a reference to it is possible.

It's also worth noting that pointers and references are identical in the ABI, so both result in passing a memory address to a function and behave more or less the same.

---

*See also: [Pass va_list or pointer to va_list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3369588/5740428)*

#### Passing `va_list` by reference is pointless in your case

However, the use of a reference to `std::va_list` is pointless in your example:

> ```cpp
> void appendFoo(const char * fmt, va_list& rVaList) {
>     vsprintf(buffer, fmt, rVaList);
> }
> ```

The issue is that `std::vsprintf` accepts a `std::va_list` by value, so when it calls `va_arg` internally, the `std::va_list` in the caller of `appendFoo` becomes indeterminate.

You could have just as well passed `std::va_list` by value, which would have been no worse.

#### About clang-tidy

The rule you're presumably talking about is [**cppcoreguidelines-pro-type-vararg**](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/cppcoreguidelines/pro-type-vararg.html) which flags all uses of C variadics.

You're not directly calling `va_arg`, so it's not entirely clear if your use should be flagged. Overall, it's not surprising though, and you probably want to disable this check if you're working with C variadics.

#### When does it make sense to pass `va_list` by reference or pointer?

It makes sense if you want to keep using the list in the caller of the function:

```cpp
std::array<int, 3> get_triple(std::va_list& args_ref) {
    return {
        va_arg(args_ref, double), va_arg(args_ref, double), va_arg(args_ref, double)
    };
}

// ...
std::va_list args;
va_start(args, /* ... */);
auto [x, y, z] = get_triple(args);
auto [u, v, w] = get_triple(args); // OK, would be UB if we passed by value
// ...
```

If we hadn't passed `args_ref` by reference, then the use of `va_arg` in `get_triple` would have made `args` indeterminate.